# Convergence in distribution question: $ (X_n+Y_n)^{-1}Z_n\overset{d}\to (c+a)^{-1}b $?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Can I conclude that
$$
(X_n+Y_n)^{-1}Z_n\overset{d}\to (c+a)^{-1}b
$$
given that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}Y_n\\Z_n\end{pmatrix}\overset{d}\to\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix},\quad X_n\overset{p}\to c
$$
where $c$ is a constant? If $X_n$ wasn't present, I would be able to apply the Continuous mapping theorem. But I don't know how to proceed for this case here. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because
$$
\begin{pmatrix}Y_n\\Z_n\end{pmatrix}\overset{d}\to\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix},\quad X_n\overset{p}\to c
$$
and because $c$ is constant, Slutsky's Theorem applies to imply that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}X_n\\Y_n\\Z_n\end{pmatrix}\overset{d}\to\begin{pmatrix}c\\a\\b\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now you can apply the Continuous mapping theorem.